# Android: Listview NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I've written a simple android list view, but it is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException during run time. Checked it in debug mode and it seems the findViewbyId is returning null. 
So when I get to the setAdapter it throws the exception. But the list does exist in the R.java file and the main.xml. How can I fix this?

```
    setContentView(my.namespace.R.layout.main);
    String[] a={"asd","asdsad"};
    ListView lt;
    lt = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);        
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,my.namespace.R.layout.rowitem, a);
    lt.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show me the code of rowitem.xml file?

Comment: You seem to be referring to different R files (my.namespace.R and R). You may look at `ListActivity` if what you want is just a `ListView` in which case you do not need to call `setContentView`

Comment: are you using custom `ArrayAdapter`? @Rajesh I think `setContentView` is for main `Activity`.

Comment: @Mayank, please read his question. `findViewById` is returning null, which means the layout (and hence the View hierarchy) does not contain the `View` with the specified id. And my suggestion was to use an Activity that extends `ListActivity`

Answer (score 2):

Is your activity extends ListActivity? You dont need a separate layout if you extend ListActivity.  See [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Wirte this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,my.namespace.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a);
```

Refer [THIS](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/11/simple-listview-example-in-android_13.html)